# How to convert Kafka from docker-run command to docker-compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am building Kafka CDC but following the document, it runs many docker-run commands.

I want to put it all into a `docker-compose.yml` but I fail at 1 last command I can not convert to

The below are the commands

```
docker run -d --name postgres \
           -p 5432:5432 \
           -e POSTGRES_USER=start_data_engineer \
           -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password debezium/postgres:12

docker run -d --name zookeeper -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.1
docker run -d --name kafka -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.1

docker run -d --name connect -p 8083:8083 --link kafka:kafka \
                                          --link postgres:postgres \
                             -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092 \
                             -e GROUP_ID=sde_group \
                             -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=sde_storage_topic \
                             -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=sde_offset_topic debezium/connect:1.1
```

This is the line I can not convert

```
docker run -it --rm --name consumer --link zookeeper:zookeeper \
                                    --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka:1.1 \
               watch-topic -a bankserver1.bank.holding --max-messages 1 | grep '^{' | jq
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` so far

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka
    ports:
     - 9092:9092
    links:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres:9.6
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=user
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
     - 5005:5005
    links:
     - kafka
     - postgres
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_source_connect_statuses
  consumer:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.1
    links:
     - zookeeper
     - kafka
    command: watch-topic -a bankserver1.bank.holding --max-messages 1 | grep '^{' | jq
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, everything run normally. But the `consumer` always fail with this output.

```
The ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT variable must be set, or the container must be linked to one that runs Zookeeper.
consumer_1   | WARNING: Using default BROKER_ID=1, which is valid only for non-clustered installations.
consumer_1   | The ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT variable must be set, or the container must be linked to one that runs Zookeeper.
```

--- Update
For now I just want to read and shootdown. Making sure it works first.

Later then I will have a source handle those reading stuff.

```
docker run -it --rm --name consumer --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka debezium/kafka:1.1 watch-topic -a bankserver1.bank.holding | grep --line-buffered '^{' | <your-file-path>/stream.py > my-output/holding_pivot.txt
```

Comment: Why do you want to do it ? Last command will run container read single message and shootdown?

Comment: Yeah I want it do read single message and shootdown, I just want it to work first. Then I change the code to prevent it shootdown later. I updated the post @VovaBilyachat. Thanks for your question

Comment: My point is that running that with docker compose does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Following will work...
The points are

- I don't know why, but ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT and KAFKA_BROKER do not be set automatically.
- You must break commands into a list.
- Finally, pipe command had not run inside container.

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper
    ports:
     - 2181:2181
     - 2888:2888
     - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka
    ports:
     - 9092:9092
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
  postgres:
    image: debezium/postgres:9.6
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_USER=user
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect
    ports:
     - 8083:8083
     - 5005:5005
    environment:
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_source_connect_statuses
  consumer:
    image: debezium/kafka:1.1
    environment:
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - KAFKA_BROKER=kafka:9092
    command: 
     - watch-topic 
     - -a 
     - bankserver1.bank.holding 
     - --max-messages 
     - "1"
```

Comment: _don't know why_ - The debezium conatiners have default values for those. `broker` and `zookeeper`, I believe

Comment: I think so, I looked inside and found it.

Comment: The docker-compose automatically connects each service. So, if the service name and hostname are exactly the same, you don't need to specify the link.

Comment: `links` is a deprecated Docker Compose option. It never really was needed

Answer (score 1):

> the consumer always fail with this output.

As the error says, you need to provide a `ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT`. However, you should be using `entrypoint` there, not `command`.

In any case, I don't know if the Debezium container will have the Python modules for you to pipe into `stream.py` or what `watch-topic` does, but you don't need another `debezium/kafka` container since you can exec into the running one.

```
docker-compose exec kafka \
  bash -c "watch-topic -a bankserver1.bank.holding | grep --line-buffered '^{' | <your-file-path>/stream.py > my-output/holding_pivot.txt"
```